# CMake install a static library that is outside of the current project to the lib/ directory

Tags: c++, cmake

As title. Relatively new to CMake. I have my own C++ project A that needs to depend on a library L. I need to build L from source.

1. What's a standard place to put the source code of L
2. how can I install the built static library file to my project A's /lib directory
3. install the header files (from L's src/include directories perhaps?) to my project A's /include directory?

During my research, I referred to the cmake.org install tutorial, and the book "Modern CMake for C++".

Comment: For #1 I usually build the dependent library completely separate from my project using CMake and don't install it into my project folder at all so #2 and #3 don't apply. Instead I use `find_package( dependentLibraryName REQUIRED)` like I do with other external libraries.

Comment: An alternate option is to use [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to have it download and build the dependency as a part of building your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What's a standard place to put the source code of L

Place the source code of L wherever you want.

If you use [the ExternalProject module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add) with no download option, you'll need to use the `SOURCE_DIR` directory option of [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add). If you use [the FetchContent module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) (which is partially built on top of ExternalProject), you can use `SOURCE_DIR` to customize where the sources get downloaded to (the default location is in the binary directory's `_deps/<name>`)

> 2. how can I install the built static library file to my project A's /lib directory
> 3. install the header files (from L's src/include directories perhaps?) to my project A's /include directory?

If the library follows the two conventions you've described for installation directories and you're using the ExternalProject module, you shouldn't need to do anything other than run the project' installation step with your project's root directory as the install prefix. See the `INSTALL_DIR` option of `ExternalProject_Add` and the `INSTALL_COMMAND` option of `ExternalProject_Add`. (See also CMake's related [GNUInstallDirs module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html)).

If you're using the FetchContent module for a CMake-supporting library dependency, you shouldn't need to do anything in particular for things to work out during the development stages even without installing the library's contents in the particular way you've described.

You may also be interested in reading [CMake's "Using Dependencies Guide"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/using-dependencies/index.html) for an introduction to the topic of using dependencies in CMake.

In the end, I don't see how this matters so much where you put libs and headers during the development process, because there are mechanisms to handle it whatever you do. See [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) and [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html), or [`add_library(... IMPORTED ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) and the corresponding [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION) target property and [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I find your answer helpful. Please allow me to add a follow-up question:
There are also cases that I'm working in a constrained environment where fetch-content is not an option and there is no pre-built package in the system except for the source code of L. In this case, what would be a proper way to specify an install destination for L so that the static library and headers are installed in my project A's /lib and /include directories? Thanks :)

Comment: @Sandm4n If the dependency's build and install process uses conventional directories then my answer already answers that. Otherwise, I don't know.